# .Net Maui TimePicker is null While Running On Windows Machine

Tags: c#, maui

I have a TimePicker with the name 'timePicker3'. When I run it on android emulator, my label shows the chosen time, but when I run my app on Windows machine it throws an error.

Here is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="MyApp___Samples.DatePickerPage"
         Title="DatePickerPage">
<VerticalStackLayout Padding="10">
          
    <Label x:Name="lblShowTime" />

    <TimePicker x:Name="timePicker3"
                Time="4:59:7"
                HorizontalOptions="Center"
                Format="T"
                PropertyChanged="TimePicker3_PropertyChanged"
                />
 </VerticalStackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

and code behind:

```
namespace MyApp___Samples;
public partial class DatePickerPage : ContentPage
{
public DatePickerPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void TimePicker3_PropertyChanged(object sender, 
 System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    lblShowTime.Text = timePicker3.Time.ToString();        
}
}
```

now when I run it on android emulator it works fine:

[image]

as you see after I changed the value of TimePicker, The label's value changed too

[image]

but when I run it on windows Machine It throws an error:
*Object reference not set to an instance of an object*

[image]

[image]

Does anybody know the reason?
thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is due to the differences in the order and mechanism of initializing controls between Android and Windows platforms.
But you can add a judgment statement before using `lblShowTime`  and `timePicker3`.  In fact, this is also the usual practice for us to determine whether it is null or not before using an instance.

```
private void TimePicker3_PropertyChanged(object sender,System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e) 
{
   if (lblShowTime !=null && timePicker3!=null) {
            
       lblShowTime.Text = timePicker3.Time.ToString();
     }
}
```